# What does vim's m command do?

Tags: key-bindings

I have found a vim's short-key list https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html. But, I don't understand the `m` command's role.

[image]

Comment: first of all : this list is either not for vim or *very* outdated. read `:help mark-motions` for details about m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:h m`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#m):

> ```
> m{a-zA-Z}     Set mark {a-zA-Z} at cursor position (does not move
>               the cursor, this is not a motion command).
> ```

And a little bit under that:

> ```
> '{a-z}  `{a-z}        Jump to the mark {a-z} in the current buffer.
> ```

Which means that with `mx` (where `x` is any letter) you can put a mark on a bufffer, this way you can go back to this place in the buffer whenever you want with `'x`.

Note that:

- lower case marks are local to a buffer while upper case marks can reach anyfile
- You can use <kbd>`x</kbd> instead of <kbd>'x</kbd> to reach the column where you put the mark
- `:marks` list the current marks
- [`:h mark-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#mark-motions) is a good place to start with marks.

Comment: I have a file containing `This is a tutorial file` text. I type `mf` when cursor is in column 0 then type `'f`. Nothing is happened.

Comment: move your cursor before typing `'f` or ``f`

Comment: @alhelal Christian is right: create a second line in your buffer, go to this second line and then try to use the mark motion. Also, note that if you don't already use marks nothing force you to use them if they don't fit your workflow.